# Is there any limitation allocating FMod class?

Tags: c++, directx, fmod

I'm trying to make sounds, using FMod. I made a class using FMod, let's say it 'Sound class'. And error occurs when I make a pointer of Sound class. I found that error occurs when I allocate Sound class more than or equal to 16.
But I don't know this is the "real cause". So I ask here.

Is there any limitation allocation FMod class?

This is constructor.

```cpp
        cout << "constructor sound : " << ++count << endl; // To count how many pointers I made.
    FMOD_RESULT result = FMOD_System_Create(&m_pSystem);
    if (result != FMOD_OK) // Error occurs here when count is more than or equal to 16. Returns false.
        assert(false);

    FMOD_System_Init(m_pSystem, 32, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, nullptr);
```

I want to know whether number matters.

Comment: Is there a good reason you need so many System instances, since every system can handle up to 4095 channels?

Comment: @Botje Oh, I thought that one instance can hold only one music. I'll try that way, thanks.

Comment: Unrelated, but any reason for not doing `assert(result == FMOD_OK)`?

Comment: (The number 32 here is the number of channels)

Comment: @Friedrich No reason. That code looks more concisely.

Comment: Keep in mind that `assert` statements are not always compiled in release builds